# Android R8 Code Shrinker and AWS CodePipeLine: java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Tags: android, aws-codepipeline, android-r8

I asked a co-worker to enable AWS CodePipeLine with a Github repository to have checks for pull requests merging into the `develop` branch.

These are the commands that AWS runs in the build phase, those are defined in a file called `buildspecs.yml`

```
./gradlew ktlintFormat
./gradlew build
```

after executing the `./gradlew build` command, AWS CodwPipeline throws the following message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

As far as I understand, R8 ran out of memory when shrinking the code, the thing is, I don't kwon how to solve this in the AWS side (if it is from that side) or if I need to define some settings in a file such as `build.gradle` in order to AWS to know how much memory allocate for R8, considering that memory is the issue.

Is this from the Android project side or from AWS? Or is there any configuration missing?